# Add text to the End of each File with Notepad++ and Regex

Tags: append, notepad++, batch-processing, eof

I have 100 files and need to append a line in the end of each single file.

Is there a way how I can do this with Notepad++?

Comment: so many poor questions, so few close votes....

Comment: I do not think that notepad++ is the best tool for this kind of job. Maybe you should look for a command-line-based solution.

Comment: @mitch and @user unknown: What's your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suggest you use a batch file

```
FOR %%G IN (*) DO echo "myline" >> %%G "C:\myDir"
```

should append myline to all files in myDir

Comment: Thanks. Using batch file is make sense and practical

Answer (score 6):

The answer of Lickro is great and works with Notepad++.

Here is a screenshot of the settings:

[image: notepad search and replace]

I am adding a linebreak `\n` and then the text.

Answer (score 4):

You can search for

```
(.*)
```

and replace with

```
"\1"
```

with **multiline** regular expression option activated. In this case (.*) matches whole text in a file and because of the brackets around you can access the match using \1 and append something after that.

Comment: What question are you answering?